# Evaluation box in home page magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I want to create a box for customer to évaluate my store. The evaluation must be in the form of stars. If a guest is loged in so the évaluation is directly saved else the clic on the registratoion of the évaluation will redirect him to the login/register page. I searched on the net but did'nt find any information can you please help me find a solution thanks in advance :)